# Cloud Build, maven package, no target folder

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
    args: ['clean',
           'package',
           '-Ddockerfile.skip',
           '-DskipTests'
    ]

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
    args: ['dockerfile:build',
           '-Ddockerfile.skip',
           '-DskipTests'
    ]
```

when I run these two commands on top locally, I do have the **target** folder with **docker** folder and the **image-name** file in it

On this step it fails:
..

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
          docker push $(cat /workspace/target/docker/image-name)
```

**cat: /workspace/target/docker/image-name: No such file or directory**

I tried target/docker, app/target/docker

In My Dockerfile:

```
  ...
    WORKDIR /app
    ...
    ADD target/${JAR_FILE} app.jar
    ...
```

**Question**: how to see **target** folder, how to make
 docker push $(cat /workspace/target/docker/image-name) work?

Comment: I thought about the parallelization, so I made is sequential with waitFor. Still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

similar to answer here: [Cloud Build fails to build the the simple build step with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975196/cloud-build-fails-to-build-the-the-simple-build-step-with-maven)

- how to see target folder

  - there isn't currently a way to check the **remote** workspace for the target folder, but you can debug with cloud-build-local and write the workspace locally.
  - https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-debug-locally
  - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-local
- make sure that target/ or .jar files are not being ignored by gcloudignore or gitignore

  - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore
  - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/236
- I also wonder if the docker step is not picking up on what is being produced by the dockerfile plugin, does dockerfile:push work?

  ```
  steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
    args: ['dockerfile:build']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
    args: ['dockerfile:push']
  ```